# What is the appropriate word for these? -> one day, one month, one year and so on

Tags: word-choice

I want to know the most appropriate word for these.

- one day
- two days
- three days
- one month
- two months
- three months
- one year
- two years
- three years

The context where these appears is that they are options users of a website can select from a menu to check the data of their weight for the certain range of time.

What's came up in my head is the following.

- period
- date range
- duration

Is there right one in the above list?

Comment: Depends on whether it's a period, a duration, or a date range.  They mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

Your list of one day, two days, etc., does not match period, date range, or duration, as your list is more specific. Your list describes exact times, and your answers describe ranges of times. Like with Google search results, there is a menu that shows timeframe: Anytime, past hour, past 24 hours, past week, past month, past year.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So, do you recommend 'timeframe' as the right word for my list?

Comment: Timeframe would be most fitting. Period would be second best, I think.

Comment: I think range would work.  If I understand question correctly, the ending date of the range is implicitly today.  Users are checking their weight for one day (ago to today), or 2 days (ago to today), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use time frame (as posted previously by Anna Plummer) for something planned in the future. I'd use [***period***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/period) ***of time*** when looking back.

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/period

> A length or portion of time.
>   *‘the training period is between 16 and 18 months*’

Some fun reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_periods